# Is Titled Tuesday now 2x week still 2x a day?

Tags: tournament, chess.com, famous-events, wesley-so

It says last week [Wesley So Becomes 2nd Player To Sweep Titled Tuesday](https://www.chess.com/news/view/wesley-so-wins-titled-tuesday-february-7-2023)

> On a day when he played a match in the Champions Chess Tour, GM Wesley So also found the time to win both Titled Tuesday events on February 7. He is now the only player besides GM Hikaru Nakamura to achieve this feat in the roughly one year since Titled Tuesday began running twice a week.

It doesn't say 2x a day so maybe it really is 2x a week but not on the same day. But at least in Wesley So's case it appears to be 2x a day.

1. [Early tournament](https://www.chess.com/news/view/wesley-so-wins-titled-tuesday-february-7-2023#early) - Feb07
2. [Late tournament](https://www.chess.com/news/view/wesley-so-wins-titled-tuesday-february-7-2023#late) - also Feb07

**Question**: What's going on? Is it 2x a week but not necessarily both on Tuesday but in this particular case it was now both on Tuesday?

Answer (score 3):

According to chess.com's article "[Titled Tuesday: All The Information](https://www.chess.com/article/view/titled-tuesday)":

> Titled Tuesday is Chess.com's weekly 11-round Swiss tournament for titled players, occurring twice each Tuesday since February 1, 2022 at 8 a.m. PT/17:00 CET and 2 p.m. PT/23:00 CET.

Answer (score -3):

> Is it 2x a week but not necessarily both on Tuesday but in this particular case it was now both on Tuesday?

The clue is in the name "Titled **Tuesday**". Not "Titled Monday" or "Titled Wednesday" or "Titled Some-other-day-of-the-week". Whenever there are two such tournaments in the same week they are also on the same day - Tuesday.